# More than 500 pins

Tags: pins, shift-register

For a project I need 400-1000 pins controlled by one arduino. Each pin should work similar as arduino pin, so something like 5V, 90mA. Is using dozens of shift registers a good idea? And what power source should I connect?
My idea is following:[image]

So one shift register requires 3 input pins to control it, and if one shift register has 12 output pins, I can connect 4 more shift registers to one shift register. Is it a good idea and will it work?

Comment: Shift registers can be daisy chained. But why do you need so many pins...?

Comment: Please be more specific about what it is you try to make.

Comment: Why are you powering the Arduino and shift registers separately? And why the shift registers by batteries? 1000 pins at 90mA each will be at max 90A.

Comment: whatever you want to do, there has to be a simpler, better, and cheaper way of getting it done. tell us more and i doubt you'll regret it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't connect shift registers as a tree. That would be awfully slow.
Instead, you connect them as chains. Shift registers are meant to be
chained by connecting the serial out of one register to the serial in of
the next one, while both registers share the latch and clock lines. You
can chain as many as you want this way: a chain of four 8-bit shift
registers behaves like a single 32-bit shift register. See for example
this [Arduino tutorial on the
595](https://www.arduino.cc/en/tutorial/ShiftOut) to see how the
chaining works.

There is an issue, however, in making long chains: whenever you want to
change the state of one single output you have to shift the whole chain
again. And the longer the chain the longer it takes. Thus it is more
efficient to put in a single chain outputs that you will likely want to
change together, and use independent chains for outputs that are most
likely going to change at different times.

As for the wiring, you need three Arduino pins to drive one chain of
registers: data, clock and latch. But you can share the data and latch
pins between many chains, as long as you have a dedicated clock pin for
each chain. You should then be able to drive *n* independent chains
using *n* + 2 Arduino outputs.

As for the power, you have to estimate your power consumption (not just
the shift registers, but also whatever *they* are sourcing current into)
and find a 5 V power supply big enough to power your whole circuit.

Comment: But will shift registers support analog and digital input output pins? And lets say there are 500 pins, what approximate time is needed to update pins state? Is this resulting delay takes microseconds, milliseconds or noticable fraction of a second to update pins? Thanks

Comment: @rint: My answer was written thinking in terms of digital outputs. You can find parallel-in serial-out shift registers that can do digital inputs. Neither type can do analog, but you can look into analog multiplexers for that purpose. You may want to time a loop of `shiftOut()` to get an idea of the time required (one call to `shiftOut()` outputs 8 bits).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a whole different approach.

Look at how they built the motion-controlled coffee table:

http://www.evilmadscientist.com/?s=LED+coffee+table
[image]

It has hundreds and hundreds of connections, so they subdivided the board so they could have distributed Arduinos.

So it is possible to control that many pins, and it may be best to use multiple Arduinos.